# pythonでプログラムを実行するプログラムを作りたいですが

Tags: python

```
# coding = utf-8
import subprocess
NAME = 'cmd' 
returncode = subprocess.call(['cmd.exe', '/C', 'start', NAME])
print(returncode)
```

上記のプログラムをexeにするつもりですが、その前に上記のプログラムですとコマンドプロンプトを起動するだけでなにもしないです。
このプログラムで起動したコマンドプロンプトにpython C:\test.pyを入力させ実行しtest.pyの実行結果をコマンドプロンプトに表示させたいです。

要は上記のプログラムを実行するとtest.pyの実行結果を返すようにしたいです。

その後exeにする方法を調べてみたいと思っています。
お願いいたします。

Comment: 質問に書いてあるプログラムが実行されるコマンドプロンプトをA、test.pyが実行される予定の子コマンドプロンプトをBとしたときに、「test.pyの実行結果をコマンドプロンプトに表示」したいのはA, Bどちらでしょうか？

Comment: 「実行結果」というのは、returncode のことでしょうか、それとも test.py を実行したとき得られる出力のことでしょうか？

Comment: 最終的にはjikkou.exeファイルを起動すると、指定したディレクトリの中のpractice.pyをコマンドプロンプトで実行し、結果を出力したいです。

Comment: 質問を少し変えますと、今質問文にあるプログラムを実行すると多くの場合 `0` と出力されると思います。駒木さんが意図している「結果」というのはこの `0` のことですか？　それとも別のものでしょうか。というのも、いちいち新しい cmd.exe を起動しなくとも直接 python.exe を立ち上げてしまう方法があるのですが、それで充分かどうか知りたいからです。

Comment: 直接 python.exe を立ち上げてしまう方法があるのであればそちらの方がいいです。知識不足でした。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `subprocess.call(['python', 'C:\test.py'])`ではダメなのでしょうか？